# What's the drinking age in Barbados?

Tags: alcohol, age-limits, barbados

I've researched this many times and I've even tried reading the bajan laws. It's been very unclear to me what the law says - I've been able to buy alcohol in restaurants and supermarkets (even 40% rum) when I was only of the age 15-16.

What's the legal drinking age in Barbados? Is there even one?

Comment: Wikipedia says "It is prohibited to sell or serve any alcohol beverage to anyone under the age of 16 years" (but there is no 'de jure' legal drinking age i.e. it can be consumed at any age).

Comment: @LaconicDroid Please don't write answers in comments. If you know the answer, then please write it in an answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I didn't think a wikipedia reference was really worthy of an answer. Was really more of a subtle hint that a quick google search found the details. Feel free to delete it (and this).

Comment: @LaconicDroid well, some say 18, some say 16, some say 18 for buying, other say there's no age limit.

Comment: So, @LaconicDroid, without any good source, like a bajan newspaper or law reference, I can't see that as a valid answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [law in Barbados](https://archive.org/details/cu31924017514468/page/n4) that determines the legal drinking age. The closest law Barbados has is from the Liquor Licenses Act of 1909, where is stipulates that licensed bars cannot sell to anyone under the age of 16.

There has been [recent community efforts](https://www.barbadosadvocate.com/news/raise-drinking-age) to update the law (from age 16 to 18) because it is outdated and over a century old.

> “We are asking our leaders to raise that age from 16 to 18 and thereby
>   any person who is 18 years old who will be purchasing alcohol, they
>   need to show some form of identification to prove they are in fact 18.
>   We are also asking for penalties for persons who purchase alcohol for
>   children and also [for] persons who sell alcohol to these minors.” - Sharmane Roland-Bowen, President of the Barbados Road Safety Association (BRSA)